# Another possible 575 tags to be burninated?

Tags: discussion, burninate-system

There are currently [575 tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/202499/which-abandoned-tags-only-have-a-single-tagged-post)  that have *never* had an excerpt or wiki and have only a single post tagged (more often than not these posts are of low quality and/or are closed).

Would these tags qualify for burnination? Do they *really* offer some possible usefulness to the site? Should they be burninated (would you say they qualify)?

Comment: We can't answer that for every single one of those tags.  If you want to go through some of them and untag them because you've considered the tag and determined that it's not adding value, then go right ahead.

Comment: @Servy So I wouldn't need to post a BR for each tag I think should definitely be burninated?

Comment: No, unless you are unsure of whether or not the tag has value and want to have a discussion about whether or not it should exist, which is almost certainly not worth having for tags like these.  Well, that or if you're looking for help, but with only one question per tag, you don't exactly need help removing that one tag.

Comment: @Servy Right I understand, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: What is this obsession over burninating tags recently? Do you people really not have anything more productive to do? **How are these tags causing a problem?**

Comment: There are quite possibly more. I found [icd] via [icd-9]. The latter was used once now removed), the former twice - but inconsistent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They do "qualify" for burnination. Tags with only one use and no tag wiki are automatically killed off after six months. The system will take care of a vast majority of these for you after some time has passed.

If you want to be proactive and go through them anyways, go for it. If the tag deserves to stay, try adding a wiki for it so it doesn't get killed off. If it doesn't, retag it to a better tag or just remove the tag completely.

I will also note that there is already a group of users who watch the list of new tags and kill off really bad ones the moment they are created. Most of the tags in that list were probably deemed "worthy to be given a chance" by someone.

Comment: I thought, "*on some sites, new tags will be automatically culled and removed from the system if they are not used by at least 1 other question in a 6 month period.*", meant the tag had to have *1* or more posts to avoid auto deletion?

Comment: @Sam Key part there is "1 **other** question" - as in you need to get another question besides the one that created it. And that actually applies to **all** sites now. They removed the option to disable it, in favor of the now-implemented feature that just prevents the deletion if the tag has a wiki.